# hashHistory vs context.router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

What is the difference between `hashHistory` and `context.router`? Both of them route url and seem to work the same.

Answer (score 1):

`hashHistory` is an instance of a `history` object created by the [history](https://github.com/mjackson/history) module. It works by modifying the hash of a URL.

In React Router, a `<Router>` must be passed a `history` object. You can create and configure your own object, but for convenience, they also create `hashHistory` and `browserHistory` objects for you. Those objects can be imported and used anywhere throughout your project, including within your components. The downside to using them is that you cannot configure them yourself. If you need to use any of the history configuration options, then you will need to create your own `history` object.

```
import { hashHistory, Router } from 'react-router'

render((
  <Router history={hashHistory}>...</Router>
), holder)

// or

import { Router } from 'react-router'
import { createHashHistory } from 'history'

const history = createHashHistory({ /* configuration options */ })
render((
  <Router history={history}>...</Router>
), holder)
```

Within the components rendered by the `<Router>`, you can access the `context.router` object. That includes a number of methods from your `history` object. Caling those methods is the same as importing `hashHistory` within that file and calling whatever navigation function that you need.

```
const MyComponent = (props, context) => (
  <div onClick={() => { context.router.push('/other-page') }}>Click Me!</div>
)

const MyComponent = (props) => (
  <div onClick={() => { hashHistory.push('/other-page') }}>Click Me!</div>
)
```

The downside of this is that your components are less portable. Whereas using `context.router` will use whatever `history` object you passed to the `<Router>`, you would need to modify the component if you decided to switch from `hashHistory` to `browserHistory`.